# Bootstrap theme not rendering in .NET 6, how to solve

Tags: css, asp.net, .net-core, bootstrap-5

EDIT 2: Beware of visual studio IDE sometimes auto filling the CSS initialization for you, my problem was solved in the comments to the question

EDIT: I have verified that I have the latest bootstrap package installed from the manager which corresponds to the version used in the theme which is 5.1.3, however this does not solve the problem.

So I am trying to change the default theme of my ASP.NET core web application, but rather than rendering the theme, it seems to have stripped the website of its default theme and applied plain HTML to the webpage.
 I am attaching my code as well as a screenshot of the webpage itself, I'm kind of lost on why it is not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - BulkyBookWeb</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css~/css/bootswatchTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/BulkyBookWeb.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">BulkyBookWeb</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Category" asp-action="">Category</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - BulkyBookWeb - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

> (Website as it is rendered right now.)

[image]

Comment: the path `~/css~/css/bootswatchTheme.css` looks like it has issues

Comment: *facepalm*, feel ridiculous now. Thank you for that catch fixed my problem!! @zgood

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bootstrap is working but there are a version conflict
as the written bootstrap classes is older than the imported bootsWatch theme

you can either update your current bootstrap version in your Asp Project or get the matched bootsWatch theme version to yours.

Comment: I do have the latest package of Bootstrap 5.1.3 installed though, and it is the same version as described in my theme. Could you maybe point me in the direction of the steps you suggest I take to fix the problem? So I may see if I messed up up along the way.